# convert CSV lines into Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I have a simple csv file

people.csv:

```
fname, lname, uid, phone, address
John, Doe, 1, 444-555-6666, 34 dead rd
Jane, Doe, 2, 555-444-7777, 24 dead rd
Jimmy, James, 3, 111-222-3333, 60 alive way
```

What I want to do it get each line of the CSV, convert it to a JavaScript object, store them into an array, and then convert the array into a JSON object.

server.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var url  = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

var args = process.argv;
var type = args[2] || 'text';
var arr = []; 
var bufferString; 

function csvHandler(req, res){
  fs.readFile('people.csv',function (err,data) {

  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  //Convert and store csv information into a buffer. 
  bufferString = data.toString(); 

  //Store information for each individual person in an array index. Split it by every newline in the csv file. 
  arr = bufferString.split('\n'); 
  console.log(arr); 

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    JSON.stringify(arr[i]); 
  }

  JSON.parse(arr); 
  res.send(arr);  
});
}

//More code ommitted
```

My question is if I am actually converting that CSV lines into Javascript objects when I call the .split('\n') method on bufferString or is there another way of doing so?

Comment: Yes, by calling `split()` you are creating an Array, which is a Javascript object.

Comment: Your road naming has some strong pessimism, come on!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By doing this:

```
arr = bufferString.split('\n');
```

you will have an array containing all rows as string

```
["fname, lname, uid, phone, address","John, Doe, 1, 444-555-6666, 34 dead rd",...]
```

You have to break it again by comma using `.split(',')`, then separate the headers and push it into an Javascript Object:

```
var jsonObj = [];
var headers = arr[0].split(',');
for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var data = arr[i].split(',');
  var obj = {};
  for(var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
     obj[headers[j].trim()] = data[j].trim();
  }
  jsonObj.push(obj);
}
JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
```

Then you will have an object like this:

```
[{"fname":"John",
  "lname":"Doe",
  "uid":"1",
  "phone":"444-555-6666",
  "address":"34 dead rd"
 }, ... }]
```

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fgdt559x/1/)

Comment: Thank you for this. Could you just explain what the second line does exactly? Wha do you mean by headers?

Comment: @GGMU `arr[0]` is the first line, that is where the headers are: `fname, lname, ...`  and `split(',');` explodes the string into array using symbol `,` as deliminator.

Comment: it's good for the example only. 
if you have a different csv with line breaks in the fields (2 lines address or something it) the code will mess up badly

Answer (score 5):

Using ES6/ES7 and some functional programming guidelines:

- All variables are `const` (immutability)
- Use `map`/`reduce` instead of `while`/`for`
- All functions are Arrow
- No dependencies

```js
// Split data into lines and separate headers from actual data
// using Array spread operator
const [headerLine, ...lines] = data.split('\n');

// Split headers line into an array
// `valueSeparator` may come from some kind of argument
// You may want to transform header strings into something more
// usable, like `camelCase` or `lowercase-space-to-dash`
const valueSeparator = '\t';
const headers = headerLine.split(valueSeparator);

// Create objects from parsing lines
// There will be as much objects as lines
const objects = lines
  .map( (line, index) =>
    line
      // Split line with value separators
      .split(valueSeparator)

      // Reduce values array into an object like: { [header]: value }
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
      .reduce(

        // Reducer callback 
        (object, value, index) => ({
          ...object,
          [ headers[index] ]: value,
        }),

        // Initial value (empty JS object)
        {}
      )
  );

console.log("Objects:", objects);
```

For CSV files using `,` as separator and quotes string values, you can use this version:

```js
// Split data into lines and separate headers from actual data
// using Array spread operator
const [headerLine, ...lines] = data.split('\n');

// Use common line separator, which parses each line as the contents of a JSON array
const parseLine = (line) => JSON.parse(`[${line}]`);

// Split headers line into an array
const headers = parseLine(headerLine);

// Create objects from parsing lines
// There will be as much objects as lines
const objects = lines
  .map( (line, index) =>

    // Split line with JSON
    parseLine(line)

      // Reduce values array into an object like: { [header]: value } 
      .reduce( 
        (object, value, index) => ({
          ...object,
          [ headers[index] ]: value,
        }),
        {}
      ) 
  );

return objects;
```

**Note:** For big files, it would be better to work with streams, generators, iterators, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution if you already have an array and want that the csv header (first line) to be the object's property.

```js
const csvArrayToObj = (csvData) => {
  return csvData
    .map((csvLine, csvIndex) => {
      if (csvIndex === 0 || !csvLine.length) return null; // skip header and empty lines
      return csvLine.reduce((a, v, i) => ({ ...a, [csvData[0][i]]: v }), {});
    })
    .filter((filter) => !!filter); //filter empty lines
};

const csvArray = [
  ['name', 'age'],
  ['John Doe', 20],
  ['Jane Doe', 30],
];

csvArrayToObj(csvArray);

// output
[
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "age": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "age": 30
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using MVC Razor,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    MyNamespace.myConfig = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(new MyConfigObject()));
</script>
```

The Json.Encode will serialize the initialized object to JSON format. Then the Html.Raw will prevent it from encoding the quotes to ".

Here the entire [example](http://blog.falafel.com/convert-a-c-object-to-javascript-in-mvc-razor/)

Comment: Judge wise before adding a framework to the depedency list. Especially if all you need is CSV reader.

Comment: That link is now dead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash (or underscore) to help with this.

```
var objects = _.map(arr, function(item){return item.split(',');});
var headers = objects[0];
objects.splice(0, 1); // remove the header line
populatedObject = [];
objects.forEach(function(item){
   var obj = _.zipObject(headers, item);
   populatedObject.push(obj);
});
```

The .zipObject method will match each header to each value in the items array and produce an object.